# Add an email message function to the apex class

Tags: apex, email

Hello i im new to this site and to salesforce 
 i would like to add function in my apex class so that when it executes it will send and email with a message body based on a message defined in an apex class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Here is how we did it with the previous guy in my company:

```
String messageContents = '<h1 style="font-family: Arial">Title</h1>\n' +
'<p><b>Date</b></p>\n' +
'<p><b>Timings</b><br/>
'<p><b>Agenda</b><br/>Please click <a>here</a> for the final agenda </p>\n' +
'<p>If you have any questions relating to the event please contact</a></p>\n';



OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress 
                               where Address = 'sampleaddress@something.com'];
Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(3);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {
mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
}


String[] toAddresses = new String[] {email}; 
String[] bccAddresses = new String[] {'cc@emailaddresses.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setBccAddresses(bccAddresses);
// Specify the address used when the recipients reply to the email. 
mail.setReplyTo('reply@email.com');

mail.setSubject('Subject Body ');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setUseSignature(false);
mail.setHtmlBody(messageContents);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

You also have to set org wide addresses at 
`Administration Setup > Email Administration > Organization Wide Address` to set which email address it sends it from